# partial success & questions about improving a simple proxy using Netty 4

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I'm trying to write a simple proxy, using Netty 4. I'm quite new to the framework, so I'd really appreciate some advice/help.

The idea for now is to connect to the Netty proxy via a localhost port, and then the proxy will forward the HttpRequest to a remote host on the web (which host is of no importance).

The way it works is that I fire up the code on localhost port 26000, redirect my browser there, and I'd expect to get my GET Http request I'm sending on localhost:26000 to be redirected to the remote host I've hardcoded in the code, and get the Http response of the remote host back to my browser.

My idea was to use Netty's channel handlers, to construct FullHttpRequest and FullHttpResponse on both sides of the proxy. For now, I can do that only on the incoming requests of the proxy. The rest of the channel handlers work using ByteBuf. I based my code on the HexDumpProxy example, found on Netty's github account.

Here's my incoming requests pipeline

```
    pipeline.addLast( new HttpRequestDecoder() );        
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024));
    pipeline.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG), new ProxyFrontendHandler(remoteHost, remotePort));
```

My inbound handler class

```
    class ProxyFrontendHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>
```

On the client side of the proxy, here's the only Channel handler I pass

```
    .handler(new ProxyBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
```

My client side class for handling the remote host responses from the requests I make uses ByteBuf

```
     class ProxyBackendHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>
```

How could I enhance my pipeline in order to receive and process FullHttpResponse objects?

Again, I'm quite new to Netty, so please excuse my code errors, unfortunately I'm kinda going for a trial and error approach to see what works and what not.

If someone wants to have a look at my code, here it is. It's working correctly, but with a minimal pipeline configuration as I said.

```
public final class NettyProxy {

private final int LOCAL_PORT, REMOTE_PORT, THREAD_NUMB;
private final String REMOTE_HOST;   
private EventLoopGroup bossGroup = null; 
private EventLoopGroup workerGroup = null;

public NettyProxy(int LOCAL_PORT, String REMOTE_HOST, int REMOTE_PORT, int THREAD_NUMB) throws Exception {

    this.LOCAL_PORT = LOCAL_PORT;
    this.REMOTE_HOST = REMOTE_HOST;
    this.REMOTE_PORT = REMOTE_PORT;
    this.THREAD_NUMB = THREAD_NUMB;

    System.err.println("Proxying *:" + this.LOCAL_PORT + " to " + this.REMOTE_HOST + ':' + this.REMOTE_PORT + " ...");

    // Configure the bootstrap.
    bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(this.THREAD_NUMB);
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
         .childHandler(new ProxyInitializer(this.REMOTE_HOST, this.REMOTE_PORT))
         .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false) // necessary!! Why after the handler??
         .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 32 * 1024)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, 8 * 1024)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)

         .bind(this.LOCAL_PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } finally {
        shutdown();
    }
}

public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
} 
}
```

My server-side pipeline initializer class

```
class ProxyInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

private final String remoteHost;
private final int remotePort;

public ProxyInitializer(String remoteHost, int remotePort) {
    this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
    this.remotePort = remotePort;
}

@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {

    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline(); // pipeline : how we organize our communication        
    pipeline.addLast("readTimeoutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(60)); // timeout after 60 secs                                
    pipeline.addLast( new HttpRequestDecoder() ); // constructs FullHttpRequest (inbound channel)        
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024)); // mergers message parts into FullHttpRequest / FullHttpResponse                                         
    pipeline.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG), new ProxyFrontendHandler(remoteHost, remotePort));                        
}
}
```

My server-side Inbound handler is this one:

```
class ProxyFrontendHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

private final String remoteHost;
private final int remotePort;
EmbeddedChannel ch = null;

private volatile Channel outboundChannel;

public ProxyFrontendHandler(String remoteHost, int remotePort) {        
    super(false); // does not release! However, it is channelRead0 that releases later on
    this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
    this.remotePort = remotePort;
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {                

    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

    // Start the connection attempt.
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
     .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())     
     .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))                                    
     .handler(new ProxyBackendHandler(inboundChannel))                                          
     .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)
     .option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 32 * 1024)
     .option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, 8 * 1024)
     .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
     .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);

    ChannelFuture f = b.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
    outboundChannel = f.channel();
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {                    
                inboundChannel.read();  // read the data that was sent by the client. This data will appear at channelRead
            } else {
                // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
                inboundChannel.close();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override // writes to the remote host the incoming Http request
public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {                        

    msg.headers().set("Host", remoteHost + ":" + remotePort );

    ch = new EmbeddedChannel(new HttpRequestEncoder()); // converts FullHttpRequest to ByteBuf, pass ByteBuf to writeAndFlush
    ch.writeOutbound(msg);
    ByteBuf encoded = (ByteBuf) ch.readOutbound();        

    if (outboundChannel.isActive()) {
        outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(encoded).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                    System.out.println("wrote something");
                    ctx.channel().read();
                } else {
                    future.cause().printStackTrace();
                    future.channel().close();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        System.out.println("outbound channel is NOT active!!");
        outboundChannel.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    if( ch != null ) { ch.close(); }
    if (outboundChannel != null) {
        System.out.println("Closing inactive channel");
        closeOnFlush(outboundChannel);
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    closeOnFlush(ctx.channel());
}

// Closes the specified channel after all queued write requests are flushed.     
static void closeOnFlush(Channel ch) {
    if (ch.isActive()) {
        ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
}
```

Finally, here's my handler for the responses I get from the remote hosts I'm connecting

```
class ProxyBackendHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

private final Channel inboundChannel;

public ProxyBackendHandler(Channel inboundChannel) {
    super(false);
    this.inboundChannel = inboundChannel;
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("*** channelActive()");
    ctx.read();
}

@Override // Read response from remote host here
public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) {

    System.out.println("*** channelRead()");

    inboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                ctx.channel().read();
            } else {
                future.cause().printStackTrace();
                future.channel().close();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ProxyFrontendHandler.closeOnFlush(inboundChannel);        
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ProxyFrontendHandler.closeOnFlush(ctx.channel());
}
}
```

Comment: Whoa there..that's a lot of code for us to go through.  Try to write a [MVCE}(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This will not only help us answer your question, but you may even solve it yourself while writing one!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Ok, I removed some System.out calls and other stuff, to make it look more compact. I still prefer to have everything in one file here, to make it easier if someone wants to copy-paste.